# get reference to grand grandparent component in Angular

Tags: angular

I have a component hierarchy similar to this:

```
gggrandparent-> ggrandparent -> grandparent -> parent -> child
```

Child is displayed `absolute`ly and needs to be aware of the the `gggrandparent`s height. `gggrandparent`s height changes overtime, due to some of it's children having `display:none` and `child` needs to respond to this changes.

What is an elegant way to get the height of the `gggrandparent` inside of `child.component.ts` file? Passing @Input() multipletimes seems like an overkill. The only other options I could think of is implementing Observable pattern and plain JS, but I have a feeling angular has its own way of handling this scenario.

Answer (score 2):

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[parentHeight]'
})
export class ParentHeightDirective {
   constructor(private elementRef:ElementRef) {}

   int get height() {
     return this.elementRef.nativeElement.height;
   }
}
```

```
<grand-grand-parent parentHeight>
  <grand-parent>
    <parent>
      <child></child>
    </parent>
  </grand-parent>
</grand-grand-parent>
```

```
@Component({
  selector: 'child',
  ...
})
export class ChildComponent {
  constructor(private parentHeight:ParentHeightDirective) {}

  ngOnInit() { // or any other method
    console.log(this.parentHeight.height);
  }
}
```

This only works if `parentHeight` isn't added to any component in between because dependency injection injects the first it finds (looking from the injecting component upwards towards `AppComponent` and application root scope).
You can do this also without `ParentHeightDirective` and just include the code in `GrandParentComponent` and inject that instead, but a directive provides better reusability and allows to have nested `GrandGrandParentComponent`s while with the directive you can specify which ones height you want by deciding where you apply the directive.

Comment: Thanks for stopping by. You used parentHeight:ParentHeight in child constructor. This is probably a typo, right? I replaced it with private parentHeight:ParentHeightDirective. Still,  I am getting an undefined value inside ngOnInit

Comment: It appears offsetHeight is the way to go, since just height is always undefined. The problem is, that display:none elements are also included in the height returned, giving back height that does not match the eye.

Comment: That's the pure DOM part of the issue. I just tried to address the Angular part of the question. There isn't enough information in the question about the DOM. You are right, I forgot `Directive`